# strtok and valgrind leak c

Tags: c, valgrind, strtok

hope can help me with this issue. 
I'm working with a .txt that has a list with words. I read all the words and put them into a struct called StopWords.
My problem is that when I use valgrind it put an error with the strtok line.

```
==11976== Invalid write of size 8
==11976==    at 0x4027FC: loadStopWords (functions.c:735)
==11976==    by 0x4028D0: main (search.c:23)
==11976==  Address 0x52067d8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2,552 alloc'd
==11976==    at 0x4C2DBF6: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==11976==    by 0x4026FA: loadStopWords (functions.c:704)
==11976==    by 0x4028D0: main (search.c:23)
```

I don't really know what is happening here.

```
StopWords* loadStopWords(char* pathStopWordsFile, code *statusCode)
{
StopWords* sWords;
FILE *file;
int size; 
char* dataFileChar; 
int wordsNumber = 1;
int wordLen = 0;
char*token;
int count = 1; 


file = fopen (pathStopWordsFile, "r" );
if (file==NULL)
{
    *statusCode = ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND;
    exit(1);
}

else
{
    *statusCode = OK;
}

fseek(file,0,SEEK_END);
size = ftell(file);
rewind(file);


dataFileChar = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(size+1));
fread(dataFileChar,sizeof(char), size, file);
dataFileChar[size] = '\0';

fclose(file);

for (int i = 0; i < size ; ++i)
{
    if(dataFileChar[i] == '\n')
    {
        wordsNumber++;
    }       
}

sWords = (StopWords*)malloc(sizeof(StopWords));
sWords->words = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*wordsNumber);


wordsNumber = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
 {
    if(dataFileChar[i] == '\n')
    {
        wordsNumber++;
        sWords->words[wordLen] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*wordLen);
        wordLen = 0;
    }

    else if(dataFileChar[i] != '\n' && dataFileChar[i] != '\r')
    {
        wordLen++;
    }
}

wordLen = 0;
token = strtok(dataFileChar, "\n");
sWords->words[0] = token;

removeInvisibleCharacter(sWords->words[0]);


while( token )
{
    token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    sWords->words[count] = token;
    removeInvisibleCharacter(sWords->words[count-1]);
    count++;

}

sWords->numberOfStopWords = wordsNumber;    

free(dataFileChar);

return sWords;
}
```

I have the main of the program too, if someone need the struct or the main,please, ask me.

Comment: You get off to a poor start when you ignore the return value of `fread()`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I know, I have to fix that, but it isn't my problem now

Comment: I link indicating the offending line numbers (as comments) could help

Comment: Guessing where the line numbers Valgrind logs point to is a fairly unsafe approach fixing this issue. Please tell us to *exactly* which lines in the source you show Valgrind refers to.

Comment: @alk it's right here sWords->words[count] = token;

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you several tips:

### 1)

```
sWords->words[wordLen] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*wordLen);
```

Using the **`words[wordLen]`** does not make sense. You should be indexing by what is the number of the word you are currently processing. I think this is correct:

```
sWords->words[wordsNumber++] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*wordLen);
```

We use postfix incrementation to increase it's value by one **after** it is used as the index, so you can remove the previous line (`wordsNumber++;`).

### 2)

As the C array indexing is zero-based, change the `wordsNumber = 1;` from just before the `for` cycle mentioned in 1), to `wordsNumber = 0;`.

### 3)

What does `removeInvisibleCharacters()` do and what is the source code (or at least the signature)?

---

I will add more points here as I possibly find other problems.

Comment: Thanks for the points to fix.
It just take a string and remove '\r' character. 
void removeInvisibleCharacter(char* element)
{
 char *pos = NULL;
 if ((pos=strchr(element, '\r')) != NULL)
 {
     *pos = '\0';
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop is badly constructed and may be the problem. Here's what you can do to make it safer:

```
counter = 0;
....
token = strtok(dataFileChar, "\n");

while( token )
{
    sWords->words[count] = token;
    /* This function may be a problem on its own, need to see its code.
       In your original code, you call it twice for the first token */ 
    removeInvisibleCharacter(sWords->words[count]);
    count++;
    token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
}
```